# What interprocess locking calls should I monitor?

Tags: linux, locking, interprocess, strace, ltrace

I'm monitoring a process with `strace`/`ltrace` in the hope to **find and intercept** a call that checks, and potentially activates some kind of globally shared lock.

While I've dealt with and read about several forms of interprocess locking on Linux before, I'm drawing a blank on what to calls to look for.

Currently my only suspect is `futex()` which comes up very early on in the process' execution.

### Update0

There is some confusion about what I'm after. I'm **monitoring** an existing process for calls to *persistent interprocess memory or equivalent*. I'd like to know what system and library calls to look for. I have no intention call these myself, so naturally `futex()` will come up, I'm sure many libraries will implement their locking calls in terms of this, etc.

### Update1

I'd like a list of function names or a link to documentation, that I should monitor at the `ltrace` and `strace` levels (and specifying which). Any other good advice about how to track and locate the global lock in mind would be great.

Comment: You can monitor `futex` and `semop`. Sometimes `pipe` can be used for locking and ordering of processes. Shared Memory based syncronization with atomic operations don't use any syscall.

Comment: @osgx: Can you describe these atomic operations?

Comment: i'm wrong. not only atomic, but ordinal read/writes to shared memory can be used for syncro. so you can't monitor atomic and read/writes with ltrace/strace. Even futex will not do syscall every time. atomic: the easyest way is pthread_spinlock, and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html But gcc atomics are inlined

Comment: Why can't I start a bounty on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can start monitored process in valgrind, then there are two projects:

http://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer

and Helgrind

http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html

> Helgrind is aware of all the pthread
>   abstractions and tracks their effects
>   as accurately as it can. On x86 and
>   amd64 platforms, it understands and
>   partially handles implicit locking
>   arising from the use of the LOCK
>   instruction prefix.

So, this tools can detect even atomic memory accesses. And they will check pthread usage

Comment: Well I since lost interest, but I now suspect that Helgrind would be the best chance to track these things with the least effort.

Comment: Matt Joiner, Thread Sanitizer has some interesting features and trys to monitor a bit more locking types, than Helgrind. It is a product from the Google internals, so it can be better

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip, I'll check it out if I run into this again.

Answer (score 2):

flock is another good one

Comment: +1: thx. as an added bonus it's a system call under Linux, but doesn't come up on my monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

on systems with glibc ~ >= 2.5 (glibc + nptl) you can use process shared

```
semaphores (last parameter to sem_init), more precisely, posix unnamed semaphores

posix mutexes (with PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED to pthread_mutexattr_setpshared)

posix named semaphores (got from sem_open/sem_unlink)

system v (sysv) semaphores: semget, semop
```

On older systems with glibc 2.2, 2.3 with linuxthreads or on embedded systems with uClibc you can use ONLY system v (sysv) semaphores for iterprocess communication.

upd1: any IPC and socker must be checked.

Comment: And please, don't use futexes directly, if you want to retain portability (both OS and architectural).

Answer (score 0):

1. There are many system calls can be used for locking: flock, fcntl, and even create.
2. When you are using pthreads/sem_* locks they may be executed in user space so you'll never
   see them in strace as futex is called only for pending operations. Like when you actually
   need to wait.
3. Some operations can be done in user space only - like spinlocks - you'll never see them
   unless they do some waits for timer - backoff so you may see only stuff like nanosleep when one lock waits for other.

So there is no "generic" way to trace them.